# Cloning, modifying and appending with self to another DOM element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

On `click` event i'm going to **clone** the last row of my table, **find** all descendat text input, **set** a new value and a new id attribute for the row and input and then **append** to `tbody`.

```
$('#add').click(function(){

    $('tbody').append($('tbody tr:last').clone().find(':text').andSelf()
        .val('').attr('id', function(i, id) {
            var s = id.split('_');
            return s[0] + '_' + (parseInt(s[1]) + 1);
        }));
});
```

For some reason i can't understand html added is (note that this is **wrong**: `input` should be inside `tr`):

```
<input id="k_1" class="key" type="text" value="modified">
<input id="v_1" class="value" type="text" value="1326130640">
<tr id="row_1"></tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.find(':text').andSelf()
```

You want that to make a selection containing the row that itself contains the `input` elements. So something like this:

```
- tr
  - td
    - input
    - input
```

However, your code actually selects both the `tr` and the `input` elements, effectively as "root" elements in the selection. So your selection looks something like this:

```
- tr
  - td
    - input
    - input
- input
- input
```

When you `append` this selection, it's done in turn, so the `tr` is appended, then the `input` elements are: this means that they are removed from their previous position as children of the `tr`. You don't need to worry about the `find(':text').andSelf()` call.  Your code should probably look like this:

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    $('tbody tr:last')
        .clone()
        .appendTo('tbody')
        .find(':text')
            .val('')
            .andSelf()
                .attr('id', function (i, id) {
                    var s = id.split('_');
                    return s[0] + '_' + (parseInt(s[1]) + 1);
                });
});
```

Note that this does the appending *before* the selection of the `:text` elements (I use `appendTo` rather than `append` to simplify the code) and only the `:text` elements have their values changed (it makes no sense to modify the value of a `tr`).

Note also that your `tr` should have `td` elements between it and the `input` elements: it is not valid to have `input` elements as the direct children of a `tr`.

Comment: Thanks, clear and concise. +1 and answer accepted. This is another amazing example of the power of jquery!